# Firebase Crashlytics - alerts are not sent to owner email

Tags: firebase, email, crashlytics

Where email to send alerts is taken from? I'm receiving alerts to other email, not Firebase project owner's email. I can adjust alerts to disable/enable email notifications, but I can't specify email address. How to get alerts sent to owner's account email only?

Possible email is taken from Google Play Console developer's account email, not from Firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

Email notifications are sent by a Google Cloud Service. If you navigate to Firebase>Settings>Users and permissions>Advanced permission settings, the email associated with your Firebase Project should be on there. Notifications are sent to emails with one of the following roles:

roles/owner

roles/editor

roles/viewer

roles/resourcemanager.googleAdminProjectReader

roles/monitoring.viewer

roles/billing.admin

roles/firebase.googleAdminFirebaseProjectReader

roles/monitoring.editor

roles/monitoring.admin

roles/iam.securityReviewer

Comment: I recently received mail saying I neeed to update Crashlytics libraries. And my Firebase projects using outdated libraries were linked in email. That's the same email as it's set as developer Google Play Console as developer email. Projects owner set in Firebase did not receive anything, why? Possible mail is taken from Google Play Console? Some of linked projects are present in Google Play, some others don't. Google Play Console is the only place where email receiving that info is set.

Comment: Is this in regards to the MSA that went out "[Action Required] Update your apps to use latest Firebase Crashlytics SDKs before November 15, 2020"?

Comment: Yes. I can't understand why that was not sent to owner's email. Instead, alert was sent to e-mail set as "developer e-mail" in Google Play Console. But Google Play Console has nothing to do with Firebase. And some projects mentioned in email never have been published in Google Play. Also, I can't understand why Crashlytics reports from all projects are sent to developer email, I've never set it to do so and I can't disable it.

Comment: In order to debug this, I would need to some of your personal info, which I don't want to expose via Stack Overflow. I recommend you write into Firebase support to get this actioned https://firebase.google.com/support